# Amount of numbers in the array that are equal to the user entered number

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++.  I am trying to read through the array of numbers and count the amount of numbers in the array that are equal to the user entered number.  I am not sure what to do next to get it to make number = number1 and count it.  I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number[20] = {80, 52, 25, 71, 56, 90, 87, 10, 32, 80, 2, 67, 73, 50, 52, 73, 72, 20, 86, 99};

    int numberCount = 0;
    int number1 = 0;

    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 100: ";
    cin >> number1;

    while(number1>100 || number1<0) 
    {
        cout << "Invalid number,enter again" << endl;
        cin >> number1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1)
    {

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to index into an array?  Do you know how to use `if`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function in the standard library for this, in the `<algorithm>` header:

```
int numberCount = std::count(number, number + 20, number1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to test whether `number1` is equal to each value stored in the array. Using the variable `i` as an index, which you already have set up in the for loop, you can access the array's values one by one and compare with `number1`. If they match then you increment the counter variable.

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1)
{
    // the next line tests whether the value of variable `number1` is equal
    //    to the value stored in the `number` array, at the index `i`
    if(number1 == number[i])
    {
         numberCount += 1;       // if there is a match, increment the counter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare each entry in the array 'number[]' against the number supplied by the user 'number1':

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if (number1 == number[i])
    {
        numberCount++;
    }
}
```